# Graph search - find most productive route

Tags: python, graph-theory, networkx

I'm working on a graph search problem that can be distilled to the following simpler example:

**Updated to clarify based on response below**

The Easter Bunny is hopping around the forest collecting eggs.  He knows how many eggs to expect from every bush, but every bush has a unique number of eggs.  It takes the Easter Bunny 30 minutes to collected from any given bush.  The easter bunny searches for eggs 5 days a week, up to 8 hours per day.  He typically starts and ends in his burrow, but on Tuesday he plans to end his day at his friend Peter Rabbit's burrow.  Mrs. Bunny gave him a list of a few specific bushes to visit on specific days/times - these are intermediate stops that must be hit, but do not list all stops (maybe 1-2 per day).  **Help the Easter Bunny design a route that gives him the most eggs at the end of the week.**

**Given Parameters:**  undirected graph (g), distances between nodes are travel times, 8 hours of time per day, 5 working days, list of (node,time,day) tuples (r) , list of (startNode, endNode, day) tuples (s)

**Question:** Design a route that maximizes the value collected over the 5 days without going over the allotted time in any given day.

**Constraints:** visit every node in r on the prescribed time/day. for each day in s, start and end at the corresponding nodes, whose collection value is 0. Nodes cannot be visited more than once per week.

**Approach:** Since there won't be very many stops, given the time at each stop and the travel times (maybe 10-12 on a large day) my first thought was to brute force all routes that start/stop at the correct points, and just run this 5 times, removing all visited nodes.  From there, separately compute the collected value of each allowable route.  However, this doesn't account for the fact that my "best" route on day one may ruin a route that would be best on day 5, given required stops on that day.

To solve that problem I considered running one long search by concatenating all the days and just starting from t = 0 (beginning of week) to t = 40 (end of week), with the start/end points for each day as intermediate stops.  This gets too long to brute force.

I'm struggling a little with how to approach the problem - it's not a TSP problem - I'm only going to visit a fraction of all nodes (maybe 50 of 200).  It's also not a dijkstra's pathing problem, the shortest path typically would be to go nowhere.  I need to maximize the total collected value in the allotted time making the required intermediate stops.  Any thoughts on how to proceed would be greatly appreciated!  Right now I've been approaching this using networkx in python.

**Edit following response**
In response to your edit - I'm looking for an approach to solve the problem - I can figure out the code later, I'm leaning towards A* over MDFS, because I don't need to just find one path (that will be relatively quick), I need to find an approximation of the best path.  I'm struggling to create a heuristic that captures the time constraint (stay under time required to be at next stop) but also max eggs.  I don't really want the shortest path, I want the "longest" path with the most eggs.  In evaluating where to go next, I can easily do eggs/min and move to the bush with the best rate, but I need to figure out how to encourage it to slowly move towards the target.  There will always be a solution - I could hop to the first bush, sit there all day and then go to the solution (there placement/time between is such that it is always solvable)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way the problem is posed doesn't make full sense. It is indeed a graph search problem to maximise a sum of numbers (subject to other constraints) and it possibly can be solved via brute force as the number of nodes that will end up being traversed is not necessarily going to climb to the hundreds (for a single trip).

Each path is probably a few nodes long because of the 30 min constraint at each stop. With 8 hours in a day and negligible distances between the bushes that would amount to a maximum of 16 stops. Since the edge costs are not negligible, it means that each trip should have <<16 stops.

What we are after is the maximum sum of 5 days harvest (max of five numbers). Each day's harvest is the sum of collected eggs over a "successful" path.
A successful path is defined as the one satisfying all constraints which are:

- The path begins and ends on the same node. It is therefore a cycle EXCEPT for Tuesday. Tuesday's harvest is a path.
- The cycle of a given day contains the nodes specified in Mrs Bunny's
  list for that day.
- The sum of travel times is less than 8 hrs including the 30min harvesting time.

Therefore, you can use a modified Depth First Search (DFS) algorithm. DFS, on its own can produce an exhaustive list of paths for the network. But, this DFS will not have to traverse all of them because of the constraints.

In addition to the nodes visited so far, this DFS keeps track of the "travel time" and "eggs" collected so far and at each "hop" it checks that all constraints are satisfied. If they are not, then it backtracks or abandons the traversed path. This backtracking action "self-limits" the enumerated paths.

If the reasoning is so far inline with the problem (?), here is why it doesn't seem to make full sense. If we were to repeat the weekly harvest process for M times to determine the best visiting daily strategy then we would be left with the problem of determining a sufficiently large M to have covered the majority of paths. Instead we could run the DFS once and determine the route of maximum harvest ONCE, which would then lead to the trivial solution of 4*CycleDailyHarvest + TuePathHarvest. The other option would be to relax the 8hr constraint and say that Mr Bunny can harvest UP TO 8hr a day and not 8hr exactly.

In other words, if all parameters are static, then there is no reason to run this process multiple times. For example, if each bush was to give "up to k eggs" following a specific distribution, maybe we could discover an average daily / weekly visiting strategy with the largest yield. (Or my perception of the problem so far is wrong, in which case, please clarify).

Tuesday's task is easier, it is as if looking for "the path between source and target whose time sum is approximately 8hrs and sum of collected eggs is max". This is another sign of why the problem doesn't make full sense. If everything is static (graph structure, eggs/bush, daily harvest interval) then there is only one such path and no need to examine alternatives.

Hope this helps.

**EDIT (following question update):**
The update doesn't radically change the core of the previous response which is "Use a modified DFS (for the potential of exhaustively enumerating all paths / cycles) and encode the constraints as conditions on metrics (travel time, eggs harvested) that are updated on each hop". It only modifies the way the constraints are represented. The most significant alteration is the "visit each bush once per week". This would mean that the memory of DFS (the set of visited nodes) is not reset at the end of a cycle or the end of a day but at the end of a week. Or in other words, the DFS now can start with a pre-populated `visited` set. This is significant because it will reduce the number of "viable" path lengths even more. In fact, depending on the structure of the graph and eggs/bush the problem might even end up being unsolvable (i.e. zero paths / cycles satisfying the conditions).

**EDIT2:**
There are a few "problems" with that approach which I would like to list here with what I think are valid points not yet seen by your viewpoint but not in an argumentative way:

- "I don't need to just find one path (that will be relatively quick), I need to find an approximation of the best path." and "I want the "longest" path with the most eggs." are a little bit contradicting statements but on average they point to just one path. The reason I am saying this is because it shows that either the problem is too difficult or not completely understood (?)
- A heuristic will only help in creating a landscape. We still have to traverse the landscape (e.g. steepest descent / ascent) and there will be plenty of opportunity for oscillations as the algorithm might get trapped between two "too-low", "too-high" alternatives or discovery of local-minima / maxima without an obvious way of moving out of them.
- A*s main objective is still to return ONE path and it will have to be modified to find alternatives.
- When operating over a graph, it is impossible to "encourage" the traversal to move towards a specific target because the "traversing agent" doesn't know where the target is and how to get there in the sense of a linear combination of weights (e.g. "If you get too far, lower some Xp which will force the agent to start turning left heading back towards where it came from". When Mr Bunny is at his burrow he has all K alternatives, after the first possible choice he has K-M1 (M1
- The MDFS will help in tracking the different ways these sums are allowed to be created according to the choices specified by the graph. (Afterall, this is a graph-search problem).

Having said this, there are possibly alternative, sub-optimal (in terms of computational complexity) solutions that could be adopted here. The obvious (but dummy one) is, again, to establish two competing processes that impose self-control. One is trying to get Mr Bunny AWAY from his burrow and one is trying to get Mr Bunny BACK to his burrow. Both processes are based on the above MDFS and are tracking the cost of MOVEAWAY+GOBACK and the path they produce is the union of the nodes. It might look a bit like A* but this one is reset at every traversal. It operates like this:

- AWAY STEP:

  - Start an MDFS outwards from Mr Bunny's burrow and keep track of distance / egg sum, move to the lowestCost/highestReward target node.
- GO BACK STEP:

  - Now, pre-populate the `visited` set of the GO BACK MDFS and try to get back home via a route NOT TAKEN SO FAR. Keep track of cost / reward.
- Once you reach home again, you have a possible collection path. Repeat the above while the generated paths are within the time specification.

This will result in a palette of paths which you can mix and match over a week (4 repetitions + TuesdayPath) for the lowestCost / highestReward options.

It's not optimal because you might get repeating paths (the AWAY of one trip being the BACK of another) and because this quickly eliminates visited nodes it might still run out of solutions quickly.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!  A couple of clarifications - each bush has a unique number of eggs.  Bush(1) may contain 20 eggs, whereas bush(5) only has 3.  Each bush can only be visited once during the 5 days.   You are correct that the travel time is up to 8 hours, not exactly 8.  Also, Mrs. Bunny's list dost not contain all bushes to visit in a day, she may only have 1 specific for a particular day.  I will update above with these clarifications.

Comment: You are welcome, glad if it was helpful. Just updated the response but I am not sure what the ideal outcome is (?). Would you be after specific `networkx` code / functions to use?

Comment: added comment up above

Comment: Thanks, please see response. I don't think I will be adding any more alternatives though. I don't want to make it look like an argument :) It is possible that you are dealing with a very difficult problem and we might at some point have to tear down the useless parts of this dialogue and leave only those that reflect the best understanding of the question/response. Interesting problem nevertheless.

Comment: I appreciate the dialogue on this - I know I need to design a heuristic that encourages movement away early on, and then back (or toward destination) as the day moves on.  I think at this point I'll have to get a working model and watch behavior to figure out how best to proceed and what changes to the heuristic to make.  Thanks again!